# Loop from a specific point to another point in Java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm working on a project in Java that is kind of like a digital time-machine, it basically saves what happened on a specific sate, archives it to a specific file, and stores it in a directory somewhere for safe keeping. Right now I'm working on a password function. I have the basics down for checking if it's right or wrong, but when I input the wrong answer, the class ends after saying "Invalid Password".
Is there a way to have it loop from the end of `else` statement to the beginning of `main` so I don't have to re-execute the class everytime?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Adam {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String passwrd = "password";
        String inputPassword;

        System.out.print("Please Input Password ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputPassword = sc.nextLine();

        if (inputPassword.equals(passwrd)) {
            System.out.println("Password Accepted, Loading Archive...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Password");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a `do`/`while` loop...

Comment: Move the code for accepting the password to a do-while loop. Password must be valid to exit the loop.

Comment: A password should be hashed, and not hard coded as "password"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a do while loop, if user input is invalid then continue the loop else not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Adam {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String passwrd = "password";

        String inputPassword;
        boolean b = true;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {

            System.out.print("Please Input Password ");

            inputPassword = sc.nextLine();

            if (inputPassword.equals(passwrd)) {

                System.out.println("Password Accepted, Loading Archive...");
                b = false;
            } else {

                System.out.println("Invalid Password");
                b = true;

            }

        } while (b);

    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/P7fsOb)

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want to run some code, check the result and then repeat if necessary the most obvious structure is `do while`.

Something like the following:

```
String inputPassword = null;
do {
    if (inputPassword != null)
        System.out.println("Invalid password");
     System.out.println("Enter password");
     inputPassword = sc.nextLine();
} while (!inputPassword.equals(password));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put whole code into while(true) loop which you will break if password is walid

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    String passwrd = "password";
    String inputPassword;

    while(true)
    {    
        System.out.print("Please Input Password ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputPassword = sc.nextLine();

        if (inputPassword.equals(passwrd)) 
        {
            System.out.println("Password Accepted, Loading Archive...");
            break; //here you are getting out of loop
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Password");
            //you are not breaking loop so the program will return to the beggining
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` loops are so ugly looking, I would rather use a flag in case the password was invalid. `while(!passwordCorrect) { ... if (inputPassword.equals(passwrd)) { passwordCorrect = true; ... }`

Comment: @tbrown A flag is also very ugly, that is why `do/while` loops exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       String password = "password";
       String inputPassword;

        while(inputPassword == null || !inputPassword.equals(password)){
           System.out.print("Please Input Password ");
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           inputPassword = sc.nextLine();

           if (!inputPassword.equals(password)) {
               System.out.println("Invalid Password");
           } 
       }
       System.out.println("Password Accepted, Loading Archive...");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to have a limited number of tries to input the password. For example to have three tries to enter password, you'd have this code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    System.out.print("Please Input Password ");
    inputPassword = sc.nextLine();

    if (inputPassword.equals(passwrd)) {
        System.out.println("Password Accepted, Loading Archive...");
        break;
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Password");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added one while loop and one flag in your program. Please have a look:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String passwrd = "password";

        boolean wrongPassword = true;

        while(wrongPassword){

            String inputPassword;

            System.out.print("Please Input Password ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            inputPassword = sc.nextLine();

            if (inputPassword.equals(passwrd)) {

                System.out.println("Password Accepted, Loading Archive...");
                wrongPassword = false;

            } 
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Password");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a do-while loop :

```
String passwrd = "password";
String inputPassword ="";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 do{
    System.out.print("Please Input Password ");
   // get the password from user
    inputPassword = sc.nextLine();

    // if password matches print success and break out of loop
    if (inputPassword.equals(passwrd)) {
       System.out.println("Password Accepted, Loading Archive...");
       break;
    } 
    else{
       System.out.println("Invalid Password");
     }

   }while(true);
```

Comment: why not `while (true)` here?

Answer (score 0):

Use a do-while loop. Also, your code has some security issues:

1. Don't use System.in for passwords. Use Console instead. (However, if you run the program from an IDE, you may not have a Console. In that case, use a GUI method instead.)
2. Hash your password straight after you input it.
3. Clear your password buffer as soon as possible after input (i.e. overwrite it). See [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) documentation.

   ```
   Console con = System.console();
   if (con == null)
       throw new IOException("This JVM has no console");

   boolean pwdCorrect;
   do {
       char[] inputPassword = con.readPassword("Please input password: ");
       String hashedInputPassword = hashPassword(inputPassword);  // search Internet for how to hash a password
       for (int i = 0; i < inputPassword.length; i++)
           inputPassword[i] = '\0';
       pwdCorrect = isValidPassword(hashedInputPassword);  // e.g. by looking it up in a password file
       if (pwdCorrect)
           System.out.println("Password accepted. Loading archive...");
       else
           System.out.println("Invalid password.");
   } while (!pwdCorrect);
   ```